# Loopback where -> like query

Tags: loopbackjs

I am using loopback 1.0

```
http://localhost:3000/api/cvp/profiles?filter={"where": {"profileId": {"like" : "%1214%"}}}
```

Causes a syntax error: "message": "Unexpected token %"

This query works fine if i omit the % characters, however the result is a single record that matches '1214' exactly.

Comment: What type of connector are you using or what database?

Comment: i am using mssql connector with SQL Server Database

Comment: I'm using the same url format to access a String attribute in a MongoDB collection and it works. However, I can't make it work when it's a Number attribute.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at this example? https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-relations-basic. I think you want to use filter like '/api/customers?filter[include][reviews]=author&filter[where][age]=21'.